# ESP32 worse performance using broadcast than unicast

Tags: esp32

I am trying to advertise JSON data to multiple devices connected to the ESP32 SoftAP using broadcast messages, however they are not arriving in a correct way.

When I'm sending the data every 20ms, it comes like this:

```
Message received        Time delta: 3.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 183.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 182.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 181.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 181.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 181.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 5.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 187.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 181.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 182.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 181.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 4.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.9 ms
```

But, when I send the unicast message it looks like this then:

```
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 17.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 23.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 128.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 7.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 126.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 7.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 57.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 51.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 8.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 51.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 6.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 36.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 4.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 36.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 4.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 40.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 17.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 113.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 115.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 127.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 7.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 123.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 13.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 118.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 13.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 114.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 116.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 16.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 129.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 4.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 126.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 8.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 123.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 11.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 120.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 12.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 29.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 11.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 42.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 24.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 15.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 37.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 3.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 41.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 2.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 17.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 33.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 7.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 23.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 16.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 23.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 45.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 1.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 14.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 23.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 23.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 17.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 22.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 24.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 16.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 24.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 17.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 19.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
Message received        Time delta: 23.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 17.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.2 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.8 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 21.1 ms
Message received        Time delta: 23.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 18.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 31.0 ms
Message received        Time delta: 9.7 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.9 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.6 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.4 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.3 ms
Message received        Time delta: 20.5 ms
```

As you can see it is much better, has sporadic hiccups, but the difference is visible.
On Wireshark the data sent is all consistent every 20ms.
In both cases the decoded data is 100% complete, the indexes match, no UDP packets are lost, just the problem with time consistency of real-time data stream.

The code to receive the UDP packets is kept as simple as possible:

```
static void udp_task(void *pvParameters)
{
    char *rx_buffer[2048];
    int addr_family = 0;
    int ip_protocol = 0;
    
    for (;;) {
        struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
        dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        dest_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        addr_family = AF_INET;
        ip_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

        int sock = socket(addr_family, SOCK_DGRAM, ip_protocol);
        int err  = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));

        for (;;) {
            struct sockaddr_in source_addr; 
            socklen_t socklen = sizeof(source_addr);

            memset(rx_buffer,  0, sizeof(rx_buffer));
            memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

            int len = recvfrom(sock, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer) - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&source_addr, &socklen);
            if (len > 0) {
                printf("Message received\t");
                TIME_END();
                TIME_START();
            } else {    // No data
                vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1));
            }
            vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1));
        }
    }
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

I tried changing the priority of the tasks, followed the information on Espressif site for LWIP performance optimization, changing the way messages are sent.